# CTFrame clipping first line of text

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-text, ctframe

I am running into a problem while using Core Text, where the first line of the text I display in a `CTFrame` is cut off at the top, as seen in the screenshot below, with the character "B":

[image: Example of CTFrame clipping first line]

I think I'm doing something wrong while setting the leading in the `CTFrame`. My code is below:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    NSAttributedString *myString;

    //Create the rectangle into which we'll draw the text
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, self.bounds);

    //Flip the coordinate system
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    //Setup leading (line height)
    CGFloat lineHeight = 25;
    CTParagraphStyleSetting settings[] = {
        { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMinimumLineHeight, sizeof(CGFloat), &lineHeight },
        { kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierMaximumLineHeight, sizeof(CGFloat), &lineHeight },
    };

    CTParagraphStyleRef paragraphStyle = CTParagraphStyleCreate(settings, sizeof(settings) / sizeof(settings[0]));
    NSDictionary * attrs = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:

                                (__bridge id)CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef) font.fontName, font.pointSize, NULL) ,
                                (NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName,

                                (id)textColor.CGColor,
                                (NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,

                                (__bridge id) paragraphStyle,
                                kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                nil];

    myString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attrs];
    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)myString);
    CTFrameRef frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0,[myString length]), path, NULL);

    CTFrameDraw(frame, context);
    CFRelease(frame);
    CFRelease(framesetter);
    CFRelease(path);
}
```

Other SO posts ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017593/setting-line-spacing-in-a-ctframe) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511830/how-does-line-spacing-work-in-core-text-and-why-is-it-different-from-nslayoutm)) are not really helpful.

How can I prevent the `CTFrame` from clipping the first line?

**--EDIT--**

Reducing `lineheight` to 20:

`lineheight` from the second line onwards is respected, but the baseline of the first line of text is less than 20 below the top.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem. In the end it turned out to be the location at which I flipped the coordinate system, and by flipping it earlier on in the code the problem fixed itself.

Comment: I noticed that you got your solution years ago. But could you help me elaborate more what do you mean by "flipping it earlier"? Because from what I read through your code in the question section, it directly do the flipping once the `CGMutablePathRef` is created.

Answer (score 0):

Here `CGFloat lineHeight = 25;` I am sure (from your screen shot) its less than font size you are currently using (`font.pointSize`).
This is the only reason of clipping top of text, as text size not able to fit in 25 points of height.

You have two options:

1) Remove `paragraphStyle` and its related code. Replace your  `NSDictionary * attrs = …` by following code.

```
NSDictionary * attrs = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               (__bridge id)CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef) font.fontName, font.pointSize, NULL) ,
                                (NSString*)kCTFontAttributeName,
                                (id)textColor.CGColor, (NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                nil];
```

`CTFrameDraw()` will take care for line height automatically.

2) Or always provide lineHeight greater than your max font size. Like `lineHeight = font.pointSize + somemargine`;

To understand above explanation try this:
In your current code set your `lineHeight = 20;`; you can see more text will be clipped from top line and second line text will be more closed to bottom of its top line.

Comment: I originally thought this, but measuring from the top to the baseline shows that the first line is much less than the specified `lineheight` while the second line onwards was exactly as specified. See the edit in the question.

Comment: Second and third lines are using standard space between two lines. if you go below line-height too much (eg. 10) you can see clipping of them also. 
Do one thing, comment out   (__bridge id) paragraphStyle, kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName,
And try without line spacing and paragraphStyle.